# Passing Json data to HTML template

Tags: jquery, html, json

I'm new to web-development, I honestly don't know even what question to ask.
So I'll just explain what I want to do.

I'm making a website that renders a random quote. I already selected an API for this:

```
$.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=", function(a) {
  $("body").append(a[0].content + "<p>— " + a[0].title + "</p>")
});
```

Which gives me:

```
Complexity is the enemy of reliability.

— Kyle Matthew Hansen
```

Now, I created a general skeleton in HTML to structure my website, how would I pass these json elements into my HTMl template so I can manipulate them?

So, I'm guessing I want to access the `a[0].content` and `a[0].title` elements in my HTML so I can place them where I want them and style them.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
<body>
...
<div id="quotes">

</div>
...
</body>
```

And JS:

```
$.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=", function(a) {
  var quote = a[0].content;
  var author = a[0].title;
  var quoteHTML = $('<div class="quote"><div class="quoteBody">'+quote+'</div><div class="quoteAuthor">'+author+'</div>';
  $('#quotes').append(quoteHTML);
});
```

And then in CSS, you can style all quotes with .quote, .quoteBody, .quoteAuthor, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already created HTML, You can use [jQuery templates](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl)

```js
var item = {
  content: "Complexity is the enemy of reliability.",
  title: 'Kyle Matthew Hansen'
};
$("#myTemplate").tmpl(item).appendTo(".container");
```

```css
.content {
  color: green
}
.title {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>

<script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <div>
    <div class="content">${content}</div>
    <span class="title">${title}</span>
  </div>
</script>
<div class='container'>
</div>
```

Comment: I haven't really created the html, just a general template.

Comment: So I don't need to create anytihng of this in the html template? I see that all the creation of `div`'s and `class` are done in the actual jquery part of the template

Comment: @tadm123, You need to create HTML in tempalte